# Useful spider tanks

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, warfare, science-fiction

I love spider tanks, ever since I watched that episode of [Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Stand_Alone_Complex), with an experimental spider tank going rogue.

---

Most of them consist of three main parts:

- **The forebody**, which mainly contains the sensors, the ammunition holder of the primary (machine gun) weapon, and the Central
  processing Unit.
- **The post body** contains the power generators, the ammunition holder of the secondary (railgun) weapon.

Regardless of type, all spider tanks possess

- **3 pairs of legs**, which are made out of [artificial muscle tissues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_muscle)(more precisely, [vanadium dioxide](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/artificial-muscle-with-1000-times-the-power-of-a-human-muscle.280308/)) and have a few traits designed after the [world's cutest
  spider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhpL5h8sEHo) (the combination of a few). These legs are usually protected
  by reinforced plates and have claws and retractable wheels on them
  as a way of faster travel, and more effective climbing.

---

[image: HAW]

*A military spider tank from Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex* (video link in the picture :)

Their armor and weapons are mostly dependent on their size. Larger ones usually have a "stinger railgun", that can be moved around with a high degree of freedom, enabled by the same types of artificial muscle.

Even the heaviest ones are relatively light-weight (because they're mainly built out of carbon allotropes), as all spider tanks are capable of jumping up to 15 meters high, via their powerful legs.

---

**Now, I wonder, whether these tanks have some sort of a "fatal flaw", that I overlooked *(we're talking about modern day and near future settings, the 40k one was just there for the lulz)*?**

Comment: Downvoted as well as VTC'd as *unclear what you are asking* because there is a lot of fluff distracting from the actual question and even statements saying that the fluff is unnecessary and distracting.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I don't get it.  99,9999 percent f that stuff was about the tanks and their inner working.

Comment: We have a [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on the Meta Site. You can test questions there by posting them as answers to that Post and then waiting at least 24 hours. People will comment on the general stuff, such as on-topic, grammar, spelling, missing information, ... Maybe you could try using that for your next question.

Comment: I think you should ask the question there http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vincent These tanks are somewhat different, the wheel idea was from Ghost in the shell, but aside from, that there are significant differences.

Comment: The major problem with spider tanks is mechanical complexity. Introducing more degrees of freedom and more moving parts causes more issues. For example, saying any single part has a 0.001% chance of failure on any given day may sound low but it's not: let's say it has 50,000 parts (an average car has maybe 30,000). That would mean the spider tank has mechanical issues every other day. A less complex robot with less parts can therefore be more reliable.

Answer (score 10):

When we talk about reliability, there is a motto:

> What is not there cannot get broken

Legs and joint are the key weak point in your concept design, expecially if you want to move around some tons of body and even jump. You are now multiplying this weak point by 6, which gives both an easy target to any enemy wanting to take the tank down and a nightmare to reliability engineers trying to make the thing operate as intended.
Sure you can reinforce the hull to withstand anti tank shells, but doing the same on joints which are supposed to move around is another story.

Comment: I prefer: "perfection is attained not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing more to remove".

Answer (score 4):

Their legs are vulnerable - they have a large surface area to volume, which means that they won't be able to be heavily armored, as any added mass on the legs would greatly restrict mobility (moving legs -> moving tank, adding weight -> slower legs -> slower robot) - very similar to how cars try to minimize their unsprung wheel weight as much as possible in order to remain fast & efficient. Furthermore they have many exposed joints which are vulnerable to getting gunk / sludge / stuff stuck in them, which would make them unable to move

Speaking of efficiency, jumping is not an efficient maneuver - while I won't doubt your 15m jumping ability, as you can hand-wave an energy source, you will also need to hand-wave it as to why it won't make sense to use that energy source in a more efficient method (i.e. traditional tank, flying robot, whatever)

You mentioned wheels on the legs - All of the above still applies, you need to not only make it possible, but make it somehow better than the alternative (normal wheeled vehicle, or even compared to a tread-drive tank). Strong, light-weight armor? Why not put a plate 2x as thick on a regular tank for more protection?

That said, there is one distinct advantage that the legs give your tanks - that is they can step over large obstacles or cross very difficult terrain. You may want to reference the AT-ATs from star wars and see how their legged tanks could adapt to various terrains.

Comment: When looking for fatal flaws, I would also reference the AT-ATs and AT-STs. They were destroyed by speeders, and teddy bears respectively. Those joints are vulnerable.

Comment: I can only repeat myself, diamond has a density that would still be in the light metal category (lower than 5gramms/a cubic centimeter), not to mention carbon nanotubes and graphene, the tanks are supposed to out maneuver regular tanks, and be able to climb walls for height advantage.

Comment: Nothing armored enough to withstand the shell of a tank can climb walls. No metal is light enough, diamond isn't light enough. Physics wise not possible.

Comment: @Mormacil With [lasers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_protection_system), who needs armor?

Comment: The moment you switch to lasers and forego armor your opponent switches to ballistic weapons. A tank armed with a regular cannon will also be able to fire significantly longer then one based on lasers unless if has a tiny internal cold fusion reactor. But if that's in the cards particle beams are superior to lasers anyway. And you might as well weaponized an Orion Drive.

Comment: @Mormacil [The gyroid armor material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#3D)

Comment: @RedactedRedacted it doesn't really matter how advanced your armor gets, it's a question of why is it better on a spider tank than a regular tank, which would get the same benefits of a strong, lightweight armor, only be able to utilize it more efficiently

Comment: @user2813274 In case of smaller ones, their greatest advantage is the ability to navigate through urban areas more effectively, and that they can climb. For the heavier ones, their main weapon's versatility and the ability to walk through rough and vertical terrains.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted so the terrain I understand, but why is the weapon special to a spider tank? can't it be mounted on a normal tank?

Comment: @user2813274 It could be, but [mother nature is just too awesome.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzAF7WuXhKA)

Comment: @BobTheAverage yes a movie-made monstrosity that is designed to fall over when the cable releases but somehow has no trouble walking before when the aircraft is actually pulling said cable (and the fact that they needed a visible pushrod to actually make one of them fall over) is most definitely a perfect analogy for a military, purpose designed 6+legged walker design meant for city combat! Also those teddy bears had set up specific traps by LIFTING TREES IN THE AIR that somehow went unnoticed, thats months of planning, measuring walker height and walk area's and stealthy work+concealment

Comment: Without any of the "teddy bear" pre-build traps, 2 walkers would have been destroyed. 1 because of bad design (YOU DONT OPEN HATCHES IN COMBAT! Imagine an elite Abrahams driver opening the hatch during combat because someone knocked on it while it was moving!) And the other because these same "legion of best troops" did not communicate the capture of their own walkers by someone who's best chance of impersonating an imperial is going "HHRRRRRRRRRRR". So yes, Star Wars movie-design and plot convenience is definitely a benchmark for all walkers!